Calling camera on android in blazor server
I have this code:
@page "/Skaner"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@using BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS

<BarcodeReader Title="Skanuj kod kreskowy"
               StartCameraAutomatically="true"
               ShowStart="true"
               ShowReset="true"
               ShowToggleTorch="true"
               ShowVideoDeviceList="true"
               VideoWidth="300"
               VideoHeight="200"
               OnBarcodeReceived="HandleBarcodeReceived" />



@code {
    private void HandleBarcodeReceived(BarcodeReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Przetwarzaj zeskanowany kod
        Console.WriteLine($"Zeskanowany kod: {args.BarcodeText}");
        // Możesz dodać logikę do wyświetlenia lub przetworzenia zeskanowanego kodu
    }
}

Everything works when I run it on Windows.
Things get worse when I want to run it on Android because it says something like this: "Skanuj kod kreskowy
Can't enumerate devices, method not supported. Error: Can't enumerate devices, method not supported. at t.BrowserMultiFormatReader. (http://192.168.0.78:8082/_content/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/zxingjs.index.min.js:15:28105) at Generator.next () at http://192.168.0.78:8082/_content/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/zxingjs.index.min.js:15:27264 at new Promise () at P (http://192.168.0.78:8082/_content/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/zxingjs.index.min.js:15:27009) at t.BrowserMultiFormatReader.listVideoInputDevices (http://192.168.0.78:8082/_content/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/zxingjs.index.min.js:15:27944) at Object.listVideoInputDevices (http://192.168.0.78:8082/_content/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/BlazorBarcodeScanner.js:92:77) at http://192.168.0.78:8082/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3047 at new Promise () at y.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (http://192.168.0.78:8082/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3004"
The application is hosted by IIS in the Blazor Server architecture. I use it and their website, for example on Android, works, i.e. a window asking for permission to use the camera opens.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/#readme-body-tab
https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS/#readme-body-tab
Any tips why it's not working?

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I think you need an SSL certificate

Android mobile devices require direct user action and permissions.  Clearly, the device's browser does not accept that you have sufficient permissions to access its cameras.  Generally, the easiest way to achieve this is to open up the camera permissions dialogue in response to a button click in JavaScript.  Don't try to initialize automatically.

It worked, but it only reads 2D codes and I want it to also read 1D codes

Once you can actually use the camera without error, recognition is purely programmatic-- it will take in the images and process them.  If you are still having problems, it's something with your function call parameters, configuration, etc. i.e. it's a different issue.
